# How can I hide/disable a specific menu item and a specific page (node) from all non-default languages?

Tags: i18n-l10n

Drupal 8 / Muli-Language Site:

There is a specific page that we need to hide/disable along with its menu link if the current site language is not the default (English).

How can this be done?

Comment: Is the Published field translatable for the content type of this node?

Comment: Perfect! That did it. Thank you :)